# Can't run Curve25519 implementation on Android device - able to on PC

Tags: java, android, public-key-encryption, elliptic-curve

I am trying to port a Java implementation of a authentication mechanism that uses Curve25519.
The libraries work perfect on my PC. But when I run it on an android device - I get a stackoverflow.

The Curve25519 implementation does have a lot of recursive calls but my question is why is it capable of running on my PC and not on my Moto G. Is this an Android limitation?

**The error throws up in the public key method of the Curve Implementation that too inside the publicKeyFrom512 and somewhere in the scalarmult function.**

Here is the android login activity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    SecureRandom secureRandomGenerator = null;
    try {
        secureRandomGenerator = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] randomBytes = new byte[256];
    secureRandomGenerator.nextBytes(randomBytes);
    byte[] privateKey = HMACSHA256.mac(randomBytes, "www.example.com");
    // STEP 5: Synthesize a public key by using the result from STEP 4
    byte[] publicKey = Curve25519.publickey(privateKey);

    byte[] signature = Curve25519.signature(
            "www.example.com".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")),
            privateKey, publicKey);
    System.out.println(signature.toString());
    try {
        boolean check = Curve25519.checkvalid(signature,
                "www.example.com".getBytes(), publicKey);
        Log.d("TRUE?", Boolean.toString(check));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am using this implementation of Curve25519

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;

/* Written by k3d3
 * Released to the public domain
 */

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
public class Curve25519 {
    static final int b = 256;
    static final BigInteger q = new BigInteger("57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819949");
    static final BigInteger qm2 = new BigInteger("57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819947");
    static final BigInteger qp3 = new BigInteger("57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819952");
    static final BigInteger l = new BigInteger("7237005577332262213973186563042994240857116359379907606001950938285454250989");
    static final BigInteger d = new BigInteger("-4513249062541557337682894930092624173785641285191125241628941591882900924598840740");
    static final BigInteger I = new BigInteger("19681161376707505956807079304988542015446066515923890162744021073123829784752");
    static final BigInteger By = new BigInteger("46316835694926478169428394003475163141307993866256225615783033603165251855960");
    static final BigInteger Bx = new BigInteger("15112221349535400772501151409588531511454012693041857206046113283949847762202");
    static final BigInteger[] B = {Bx.mod(q),By.mod(q)};
    static final BigInteger un = new BigInteger("57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819967");
    
    static byte[] H(byte[] m) {
        MessageDigest md;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
            md.reset();
            return md.digest(m);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    static BigInteger expmod(BigInteger b, BigInteger e, BigInteger m) {
        //System.out.println("expmod open with b=" + b + " e=" + e + " m=" + m);
        if (e.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
            //System.out.println("expmod close with 1z");
            return BigInteger.ONE;
        }
        BigInteger t = expmod(b, e.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2)), m).pow(2).mod(m);
        //System.out.println("expmod 1/2 t="+t+" e="+e+" testbit="+(e.testBit(0)?1:0));
        if (e.testBit(0)) {
            t = t.multiply(b).mod(m);
        }
        //System.out.println("expmod close with " + t);
        return t;
    }
    
    static BigInteger inv(BigInteger x) {
        //System.out.println("inv open with " + x);
        //System.out.println("inv close with " + expmod(x, qm2, q));
        return expmod(x, qm2, q);
    }
    
    static BigInteger xrecover(BigInteger y) {
        BigInteger y2 = y.multiply(y);
        BigInteger xx = (y2.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(inv(d.multiply(y2).add(BigInteger.ONE)));
        BigInteger x = expmod(xx, qp3.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(8)), q);
        if (!x.multiply(x).subtract(xx).mod(q).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) x = (x.multiply(I).mod(q));
        if (!x.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(2)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) x = q.subtract(x);
        return x;
    }
    
    static BigInteger[] edwards(BigInteger[] P, BigInteger[] Q) {
        BigInteger x1 = P[0];
        BigInteger y1 = P[1];
        BigInteger x2 = Q[0];
        BigInteger y2 = Q[1];
        BigInteger dtemp = d.multiply(x1).multiply(x2).multiply(y1).multiply(y2);
        //System.out.println("edwards open with "+x1+","+x2+" "+y1+","+y2+" d="+d+" dtemp="+dtemp);
        BigInteger x3 = ((x1.multiply(y2)).add((x2.multiply(y1)))).multiply(inv(BigInteger.ONE.add(dtemp)));
        //System.out.println("edwards 1/2 with "+x1+","+x2+" "+y1+","+y2+" d="+d+" dtemp="+dtemp);
        BigInteger y3 = ((y1.multiply(y2)).add((x1.multiply(x2)))).multiply(inv(BigInteger.ONE.subtract(dtemp)));
        //System.out.println("edwards 2/2 with "+x1+","+x2+" "+y1+","+y2+" d="+d+" dtemp="+dtemp);
        //System.out.println("edwards close with "+x3.mod(q)+","+y3.mod(q));
        return new BigInteger[]{x3.mod(q), y3.mod(q)};
    }
    
    static BigInteger[] scalarmult(BigInteger[] P, BigInteger e) {
        //System.out.println("scalarmult open with e = " + e);
        if (e.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
            //System.out.println("scalarmult close with Q = 0,1");
            return new BigInteger[]{BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE};
        }
        BigInteger[] Q = scalarmult(P, e.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2)));
        //System.out.println("scalarmult asQ = " + Q[0] + "," + Q[1]);
        Q = edwards(Q, Q);
        //System.out.println("scalarmult aeQ = " + Q[0] + "," + Q[1] + " e="+e+" testbit="+(e.testBit(0)?1:0));
        if (e.testBit(0)) Q = edwards(Q, P);
        //System.out.println("scalarmult close with Q = " + Q[0] + "," + Q[1]);
        return Q;
    }
    
    static byte[] encodeint(BigInteger y) {
        byte[] in = y.toByteArray();
        byte[] out = new byte[in.length];
        for (int i=0;i<in.length;i++) {
            out[i] = in[in.length-1-i];
        }
        return out;
    }
    
    static byte[] encodepoint(BigInteger[] P) {
        BigInteger x = P[0];
        BigInteger y = P[1];
        byte[] out = encodeint(y);
        //System.out.println("encodepoint x="+x+" testbit="+(x.testBit(0) ? 1 : 0));
        out[out.length-1] |= (x.testBit(0) ? 0x80 : 0);
        return out;
    }
    
    static int bit(byte[] h, int i) {
        //System.out.println("bit open with i="+i);
        //System.out.println("bit close with "+(h[i/8] >> (i%8) & 1));
        return h[i/8] >> (i%8) & 1;
    }
    
    public static byte[] publickeyFrom512(byte[] h) {
        //System.out.println("publickey open with h=" + test.getHex(h));
        BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(b-2);
        for (int i=3;i<(b-2);i++) {
            BigInteger apart = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(i).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(bit(h,i)));
            //System.out.println("publickey apart="+apart);
            a = a.add(apart);
        }
        BigInteger[] A = scalarmult(B,a);
        //System.out.println("publickey close with A="+A[0]+","+A[1]+" out="+test.getHex(encodepoint(A)));
        return encodepoint(A);
    }
    
    public static byte[] publickey(byte[] sk) {
        byte[] h = H(sk);
        return publickeyFrom512(h);
    }
    
    static BigInteger Hint(byte[] m) {
        byte[] h = H(m);
        BigInteger hsum = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for (int i=0;i<2*b;i++) {
            hsum = hsum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(i).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(bit(h,i))));
        }
        return hsum;
    }
    
    public static byte[] signatureFrom512(byte[] m, byte[] h, byte[] pk) {
        //System.out.println("signature open with m="+test.getHex(m)+" h="+test.getHex(h)+" pk="+test.getHex(pk));
        BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(b-2);
        for (int i=3;i<(b-2);i++) {
            a = a.add(BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(i).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(bit(h,i))));
        }
        //System.out.println("signature a="+a);
        ByteBuffer rsub = ByteBuffer.allocate((b/8)+m.length);
        rsub.put(h, b/8, b/4-b/8).put(m);
        //System.out.println("signature rsub="+test.getHex(rsub.array()));
        BigInteger r = Hint(rsub.array());
        //System.out.println("signature r="+r);
        BigInteger[] R = scalarmult(B,r);
        ByteBuffer Stemp = ByteBuffer.allocate(32+pk.length+m.length);
        Stemp.put(encodepoint(R)).put(pk).put(m);
        BigInteger S = r.add(Hint(Stemp.array()).multiply(a)).mod(l);
        ByteBuffer out = ByteBuffer.allocate(64);
        out.put(encodepoint(R)).put(encodeint(S));
        return out.array();
    }
    public static byte[] signature(byte[] m, byte[] sk, byte[] pk) {
        byte[] h = H(sk);
        return signatureFrom512(m, h, pk);
    }
    
    static boolean isoncurve(BigInteger[] P) {
        BigInteger x = P[0];
        BigInteger y = P[1];
        //System.out.println("isoncurve open with P="+x+","+y);
        BigInteger xx = x.multiply(x);
        BigInteger yy = y.multiply(y);
        BigInteger dxxyy = d.multiply(yy).multiply(xx);
        //System.out.println("isoncurve close with "+xx.negate().add(yy).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).subtract(dxxyy).mod(q));
        return xx.negate().add(yy).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).subtract(dxxyy).mod(q).equals(BigInteger.ZERO);
    }
    
    static BigInteger decodeint(byte[] s) {
        byte[] out = new byte[s.length];
        for (int i=0;i<s.length;i++) {
            out[i] = s[s.length-1-i];
        }
        return new BigInteger(out).and(un);
    }
    
    static BigInteger[] decodepoint(byte[] s) throws Exception {
        byte[] ybyte = new byte[s.length];
        for (int i=0;i<s.length;i++) {
            ybyte[i] = s[s.length-1-i];
        }
        //System.out.println("decodepoint open with s="+test.getHex(s)+" ybyte="+test.getHex(ybyte));
        BigInteger y = new BigInteger(ybyte).and(un);
        //System.out.println("decodepoint y="+y);
        BigInteger x = xrecover(y);
        //System.out.println("decodepoint x="+x+" testbit="+(x.testBit(0)?1:0)+" bit="+bit(s, b-1));
        if ((x.testBit(0)?1:0) != bit(s, b-1)) {
            x = q.subtract(x);
        }
        BigInteger[] P = {x,y};
        if (!isoncurve(P)) throw new Exception("decoding point that is not on curve");
        return P;
    }
    
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static boolean checkvalid(byte[] s, byte[] m, byte[] pk) throws Exception {
        if (s.length != b/4) throw new Exception("signature length is wrong");
        if (pk.length != b/8) throw new Exception("public-key length is wrong");
        //System.out.println("checkvalid open with s="+test.getHex(s)+" m="+test.getHex(m)+" pk="+test.getHex(pk));
        byte[] Rbyte = Arrays.copyOfRange(s, 0, b/8);
        //System.out.println("checkvalid Rbyte="+test.getHex(Rbyte));
        BigInteger[] R = decodepoint(Rbyte);
        BigInteger[] A = decodepoint(pk);
        //System.out.println("checkvalid R="+R[0]+","+R[1]+" A="+A[0]+","+A[1]);
        byte[] Sbyte = Arrays.copyOfRange(s, b/8, b/4);
        //System.out.println("checkvalid Sbyte="+test.getHex(Sbyte));
        BigInteger S = decodeint(Sbyte);
        //System.out.println("checkvalid S="+S);
        ByteBuffer Stemp = ByteBuffer.allocate(32+pk.length+m.length);
        Stemp.put(encodepoint(R)).put(pk).put(m);
        BigInteger h = Hint(Stemp.array());
        BigInteger[] ra = scalarmult(B,S);
        BigInteger[] rb = edwards(R,scalarmult(A,h));
        //System.out.println("checkvalid ra="+ra[0]+","+ra[1]+" rb="+rb[0]+","+rb[1]);
        if (!ra[0].equals(rb[0]) || !ra[1].equals(rb[1])) // Constant time comparison
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is the error:

> 04-15 00:37:31.317: W/dalvikvm(26308): threadid=1: thread exiting with
> uncaught exception (group=0x41614d40)
>
> 04-15 00:37:31.714: E/AndroidRuntime(26308): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 04-15 00:37:31.714: E/AndroidRuntime(26308): Process:
> com.rtindru.qrlogin, PID: 26308
>
> 04-15 00:37:31.714: E/AndroidRuntime(26308):
> java.lang.StackOverflowError
>
> 04-15 00:37:31.714: E/AndroidRuntime(26308):  at
> java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.add(FinalizerReference.java:54)
>
> 04-15 00:37:31.714: E/AndroidRuntime(26308):  at
> java.math.BigInt.(BigInt.java:24)
>
> 04-15 00:37:31.714: E/AndroidRuntime(26308):  at
> java.math.BigInt.newBigInt(BigInt.java:56)
>
> 04-15 00:37:31.714: E/AndroidRuntime(26308):  at
> java.math.BigInt.bigExp(BigInt.java:285)
>
> 04-15 00:37:31.714: E/AndroidRuntime(26308):  at
> com.sqrl.crypto.Curve25519.expmod(Curve25519.java:48)
>
> 04-15 00:37:31.714: E/AndroidRuntime(26308):  at
> com.sqrl.crypto.Curve25519.expmod(Curve25519.java:48)
>
> 04-15 00:37:31.714: E/AndroidRuntime(26308):  at
> com.sqrl.crypto.Curve25519.expmod(Curve25519.java:48)
>
> 04-15 00:37:31.714: E/AndroidRuntime(26308):  at
> com.sqrl.crypto.Curve25519.expmod(Curve25519.java:48)
> (These lines are repeated a hundred odd times)
> 04-15 00:37:31.714: E/AndroidRuntime(26308):  at com.sqrl.cry
>
> 04-15 00:41:52.842: I/dalvikvm(26712): threadid=1: stack overflow on
> call to Ljava/lang/ref/FinalizerReference;.:VLL 04-15
>
> 00:41:52.842: I/dalvikvm(26712):   method requires 12+20+12=44 bytes,
> fp is 0x5755f314 (20 left)
>
> 04-15 00:41:52.842: I/dalvikvm(26712):
> expanding stack end (0x5755f300 to 0x5755f000)

Comment: bit late I know but using `BigIntegers` opens you up to problems as shown in this wiki https://github.com/k3d3/ed25519-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the calculations causing a stack overflow.

The repeated recursive division exceeded the call stack allocated to the process.

I tried running it as an AsyncTask, but still the same issue.

I got around this by spawning a new Thread with a lot more memory (64kb) than what Android typically allocates.
I used this constructor:

```
Thread(ThreadGroup group, Runnable target, String name, long stackSize)
```

This did resolve the issue, but I am not sure how such a simple workaround is possible! 
Any comments?

Comment: It would have been probably easier to rewrite `expmod` to use an iteration instead of recursion. Or even better, use `BigInteger.modPow`